# findviewbyid error cannot resolve

Tags: java, android, fragment

I tried almost everything but it doesn't seem to work, i keep getting a cannot resolve findviewById for the buttons at the bottom. the button declarations have the same errors but I fixed those correctly, the button ones at the bottom don't seem to behave the same way. New to android, Help?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ConnectFragment extends Fragment {

public String sign = "";
public String total= "";
public Double tempDouble, tempDouble2;

public ConnectFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_connect, container, false);

    return rootView;

    // Buttons for Felony
    Button button1 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button button2 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    Button button3 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
    Button button4 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4);
    Button button5 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button5);
    //Buttons for misdemeanors
    Button button6 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button7);
    Button button7 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button8);
    Button button8 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button6);
    //Buttons for Infraction
    Button button9 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button9);
    //clear, +, =
    Button button10=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button10);
    Button button11 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button11);
    Button button12 =(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button12);




    // button 1 event handler
    button1.setOnClickListener(
            //button 1 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 1 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("100 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 2 event handler
    button2.setOnClickListener(
            //button 2 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 2 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("25 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 3 event handler
    button3.setOnClickListener(
            //button 3 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 3 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("10 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 4 event handler
    button4.setOnClickListener(
            //button 4 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 4 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("5 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 5 event handler
    button5.setOnClickListener(
            //button 5 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 5 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("1 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 6 event handler
    button6.setOnClickListener(
            //button 1 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 6 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("1 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 7 event handler
    button7.setOnClickListener(
            //button 7 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 7 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.5 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 8 event handler
    button8.setOnClickListener(
            //button 8 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 8 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.25 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 9 event handler
    button9.setOnClickListener(
            //button 9 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 9 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.append("0.013 years");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 10 event handler
    button10.setOnClickListener(
            //button 10 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 10 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    output.setText("");
                }
            }
    );
    // button 12 event handler
    button12.setOnClickListener(
            //button 12 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 12 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    output.setText("");
                    sign = "+";
                }
            }
    );

    // button 11 event handler
    button11.setOnClickListener(
            //button 11 interface
            new Button.OnClickListener()
            {
                //Button 11 callback method
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    TextView output = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    tempDouble2 = Double.parseDouble(output.getText().toString());
                    if (sign=="+")
                    {
                        output.setText(Double.toString(tempDouble+tempDouble2));
                        sign="";
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
}
}

}
```

Comment: Move your `return` statement to the end of the `onCreateView()` method.

Comment: @MikeM. Still getting the error http://puu.sh/nWva6/b6cd23a672.png

Comment: Oh, those. Assuming the `TextView`s are in the `Fragment`'s layout, call `findViewById()` on `getView()`. That is, `TextView output = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.editText);`. Or You could make `rootView` `final`, and call it on that.  Also, you might consider making your `Button` and `TextView` variables class members, and initialize them all in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Sorry, im new, but thanks for helping out. Do you mean like this: http://puu.sh/nWwdK/de4cf0bcc7.png ? Im still getting the error tho.
XML : http://puu.sh/nWwkc/7c21d5552a.png

Comment: No, sorry, those were two separate things. If you leave the `TextView` line where it was, you'd use `getView()`. If you move it there, use `rootView`, but you'd have to make the `TextView` variables `final`, or move the declaration - i.e., `TextView output;` - to the class scope, where your `String`s and `Double` are. If you move the declaration, make sure to remove `TextView` from the beginning of the initialization line in `onCreateView()`.

Comment: Sorry if this is getting annoying but i got this: http://puu.sh/nWxnJ/2ffc316dde.png am i on the right path? do i change convertview to textview?

Comment: No, that method does not belong there. `getView()` is a method of the `Fragment` class. You don't need to define it.

Comment: Oh i understand now, finally got that working, i was unaware where to put the deceleration before so thank you for that. Thing is, im getting a new error now, lol, it says it have an "unreachable statement",  http://puu.sh/nWAKU/f76a9cb827.png

Comment: Refer to my very first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing for a `Fragment` that does not have method `findViewById`. You need to use:

```
TextView output = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Also move your `return rootView` statement to the end of method.

Comment: Yes. Also put the return statement after your setClickHandlers as well. And use the same way to get `TextView` in them.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but a better way to get rid of all that boilerplate code that looks ugly, is to use dependency injection. A good framework to use that is simple and easy is `butterknife`. Your code would be much cleaner and you wouldn't have the findById and all those click events. All this is handled by bufferknife.